# Group when values in two columns are identical and calculate the mean

Tags: r

I got a dataset like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), 
  var2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1),
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I want to group rows in `var1` and `var2` and calculate the mean of `value`, and the condition is that when rows with the same `var1` **and** `var2` values will be grouped together (so it is not simply grouped by unique values in `var1` and `var2`).

The output dataset will be this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1, 1, 2),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 1),
  value = c(1, 2.5, 4))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value))

   var1  var2 value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   1  
2     1     2   2.5
3     2     1   4
```

`group_by(var1, var2)` will group both variable together.

Comment: Ah thanks, I tried something very similar at the last line but it didn't work: `summarize(vars("value"), mean)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `aggregate()`.

```
aggregate(value ~ var1 + var2, df1, mean)
#   var1 var2 value
# 1    1    1   1.0
# 2    2    1   4.0
# 3    1    2   2.5
```